# How can I access local storage from popup page in Mozilla Firefox extension?

Tags: firefox-addon, mozilla, firefox-addon-webextensions

I can access and use the local storage in my Mozilla Firefox extension background script. But I can't access the local storage from popup page. How can I do it?

Comment: Show an example of what you're doing and it doesn't work. Without knowing what you wanted to do, it's not possible to help.

Answer (score 1):

If the pop-up is an extension pop-up like BrowserAction or pageActioon pop-ups; you should be able to access both local storage (Web API) and Storage local (WebExtension API).

If the pop-up is a content script pop-up (generated from content script that is injected into web page), then it will not have access to above since it will be on a different domain than the extension.